# NavigationView NotSerializableException while pushing fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, serialization, navigation-drawer, navigationview

I am getting NotSerializableException when pushing one of my fragments in my app. I am using navigation view in my activity for side menu.

```
    Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
```

I have a ProfileFragment in my MainActivity. I am re using my EntriesList fragment inside ProfileFragment. On clicking an item in EntriesList, the EntryDetailsFragment is being pushed to main container. This is crashing the app with above message. I have included complete stack trace below.

FATAL EXCEPTION: main

> Process: com.ajith.trivado, PID: 5597
>                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing
>   serializable object (name = com.ajith.trivado.activities.MainActivity)
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1316)
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1264)
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618)
>                                                                           at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636)
>                                                                           at android.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:132)
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1133)
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:373)
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1285)
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1204)
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618)
>                                                                           at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636)
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2506)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3165)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                        Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>                                                                           at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
>                                                                           at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
>                                                                           at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
>                                                                           at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
>                                                                           at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
>                                                                           at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
>                                                                           at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
>                                                                           at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
>                                                                           at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
>                                                                           at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
>                                                                           at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1311)
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1264) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636) 
>                                                                           at android.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:132) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1133) 
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:373) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1285) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1204) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636) 
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2506) 
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3165) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086) 
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

I should see the code but I think you are sending some extra data to your fragment. The class of your object that is being sent should implement Serializable.